# Get values of multiple buttons via JQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I want to do something when a certain button is pressed via JQuery and PHP. The problem is however, the buttons on my page are dynamically generated, all with different values. So it could be three, four buttons,...etc.

The two main problems are:

1) Only the first button is recognized by Javascript, the other don't do anything.

2) I can't find a way to pass the variable id with JavaScript to my PHP code.

An example will hopefully make the problem clear:

**HTML, the amount of buttons is unknown, all with different values:**

```
<button id='button' value='$variableid1'>Do something</button>
<button id='button' value='$variableid6'>Do something</button>
<button id='button' value='$variableid11'>Do something</button>
...
```

**When pressed, I tried to activate this Javascript code:**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#button").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        data: {clicked: ?},
        });
    });

});
```

**PHP code, on the same page:**

```
if(isset($_POST['clicked'])){

//do some stuff with the variable id.

}
```

Comment: IDs must be unique. jQuery only selects the first element with a specific ID.

Comment: look into `serialize()`

Comment: @user1048676 I'm not really sure how that would help, `.serialize()` doesn't serialize buttons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IDs must be unique, you should use classes instead and for dynamically generated elements you should delegate the events:

```
$(document).on('click', '.button', function(e) {
   // e.preventDefault();
   $.ajax({
       type:"POST",
       data: {clicked: this.value},
   }).done(function(data){
       console.log(data, 'done');
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! It was the 'this' I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong you cannot have a same id for multiple elements. You need to give unique id for each element. You can have same class but not same id.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try this to get those values:

1. Have the elements have the same Class and unique ID's
2. Make the repeated buttons have the same class called button e.g.
   `<button class='button' value='<?php echo $variableid1 ?>'Do something</button>`
3. Then using jquery you can access the value of each button like so:

   ```
   $(".button").live('click',function(){    
   var valueofbutton = $(this).val();    
   alert(valueofbutton);//also put your ajax function here...   
   })
   ```

Note the use of 'live'.

Answer (score 1):

There is so much wrong here its difficult to know where to start

```
<button id='button' value='$variableid1'>Do something</button>
<button id='button' value='$variableid6'>Do something</button>
<button id='button' value='$variableid11'>Do something</button>
```

As mentioned above id's must be unique on a page, they are afterall keys to an html element not just windows dressing.

So

```
<button id='button1' value='$variableid1'>Do something</button>
<button id='button2' value='$variableid6'>Do something</button>
<button id='button3' value='$variableid11'>Do something</button>
```

If you want to load a value from a script variable to the "value' you need to do this

```
<button id='button1' value='<?php echo $variableid1; ?>'>Do something</button>
<button id='button2' value='<?php echo $variableid6; ?>'>Do something</button>
<button id='button3' value='<?php echo $variableid11; ?>'>Do something</button>
```

OR this if you have shorttags turned on on you php

```
<button id='button1' value='<?=$variableid1?>'>Do something</button>
<button id='button2' value='<?=$variableid6?>'>Do something</button>
<button id='button3' value='<?=$variableid11?>'>Do something</button>
```

If you want to know which button was pressed in the php script that processes the form data when a button is pressed you need 
to give them a name.

```
<button id='button1' name='buttons1' value='<?php echo $variableid1; ?>'>Do something</button>
<button id='button2' name='buttons2' value='<?php echo $variableid6; ?>'>Do something</button>
<button id='button3' name='buttons3' value='<?php echo $variableid11; ?>'>Do something</button>
```

Now one way of being able to search a group of thing in jQuery is to give them a class name that can be used in jQuery but does not need to be an actual css class. So lets use a descriptive name like 'jq-butset'.

```
<button id='button1' class='jq-butset' name='buttons1' value='<?php echo $variableid1; ?>'>Do something</button>
<button id='button2' class='jq-butset' name='buttons2' value='<?php echo $variableid6; ?>'>Do something</button>
<button id='button3' class='jq-butset' name='buttons3' value='<?php echo $variableid11; ?>'>Do something</button>
```

So now your jQuery code might look like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".jq-butset").click(function() {
      posting = $.post('url/to/the/phpscript/to/run/test.php',
                   { buttonname: $(this).attr('name'), 
                     buttonvalue: $(this).attr('value')
                   }
       );
       posting.done( function (data) {
        ... do something with the data returned
       });
       posting.error( function () {
         .. do something if an error occurs
       });
    });
   });
});
```